# Nested namespaces in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, namespaces, multi-tenant

Is it possible to create nested namespaces in a google app engine app?

Lets say i am modeling a multi-tenant application similar to google docs.  So I obviously need one namespace for each organization to avoid data leaks from one org to another.  However, i probably want a namespace per user also so that when i am searching for a document, i dont have to search through all the documents of all the users in that organization and again to avoid data leaks.

Whats the best way to model this?

Comment: Doing a query on a large datastore is no slower than doing a query on a small one, in App Engine. Partitioning each user into their own namespace won't save you time fetching their data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With namespaces just being strings (limited to `[0‑9A‑Za‑z._‑]{0,100}`) you *could* just use `"_"` or somewhere as your separator for your sub namespaces, so you'd have namespaces like  "%organisation_%user"

But your argument

> So I don't have to search through all the documents

doesn't seem like a strong enough reason to go down this route. Your code will become more complex (and as a result *more* likly to leak data) if you are constantly having to switch between namespaces to get at data that is organisation wide vs user wide. Performance will not be improved any more than if you were filtering your list of `documents` by a user-id field.